# Is there a way to stop express from rendering files in a static directory?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

The file server part of my application is similar to Nextcloud Files and I am storing the files in a folder that is set up in express with `router.use(express.static('files'))`

Problem is, when I upload an .html file with my application, when it redirects to /files `res.redirect('/files')` instead of rendering the files.pug template like it normally does and as specified in the router, it renders the newly uploaded .html file.

```
router.get('/files', (req, res) => {
    res.render('files', {
        someData: goingIn
    })
})
```

I've been searching but it seems more folks are stuck on serving that .html file and not many are trying to stop it. Perhaps there is a better method that I am missing. Is there a way to stop express from rendering files in a static directory?

Comment: Can you show app folder structure? What did you set here `app.set('views', '????')`

Comment: Can't you just upload the html files to other folder (such as: '/files/uploadedfiles/')?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by passing an option to express.static `{ index: false }`

This disables directory indexing according to the docs https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static

```
const options = {
    index: false
}
router.use(express.static('files', options))
```